# how to validate BIGINT in regex

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I am trying validate BIGINT mysql datatype. but I am getting error on `re101` it says the range is too large, when it goes above 5 digits.. so how to validate in this case?

```
     ^\d{1,980989}$
```

Comment: @Ankit I said I am validating BIGINT..

Comment: But it will not be guaranteed if its above that range or not..

Comment: [BIGINT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html) looks to be in a range from `-9223372036854775808 to +9223372036854775807`. Do you want to validate the numbers in this range?

Comment: From what I see, `{1,980989}` matches anything with 1 digit up to a number with 980989 digits... correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think you need that many digits to validate a BIGINT

Comment: Something more along the lines of `^-?\d{1,19}$` may be what you're after

Comment: @saac I think I am confused with the logic of the range here.. you sound correct..

Comment: @stribizhev yes... but from 0 to +...

Comment: `SIGNED` or `UNSIGNED`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
\b(?:[0-9]{1,18}|[1-8][0-9]{18}|9(?:[01][0-9]{17}|2(?:[01][0-9]{16}|2(?:[0-2][0-9]{15}|3(?:[0-2][0-9]{14}|3(?:[0-6][0-9]{13}|7(?:[01][0-9]{12}|20(?:[0-2][0-9]{10}|3(?:[0-5][0-9]{9}|6(?:[0-7][0-9]{8}|8(?:[0-4][0-9]{7}|5(?:[0-3][0-9]{6}|4(?:[0-6][0-9]{5}|7(?:[0-6][0-9]{4}|7(?:[0-4][0-9]{3}|5(?:[0-7][0-9]{2}|80[0-7]))))))))))))))))\b
```

Courtesy of [utilitymill.com](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range) :)

Add an optional `[+]?` at the beginning if you want to match `+` symbol.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nT4gC1/4)

Comment: :o that is what I feared... hhh

Comment: What about leading zeros?

Comment: small observation, is there a way to allow for -9223372036854775808 since the negative will be one greater?

Comment: @Lucas: You will have to use `80[0-8]` instead of `80[0-7]` and add that as an alternative with an obligatory minus symbol in front, I am afraid. It is not possible to add the minus and change the character class to match both positive and negative values.

Answer (score 3):

Slight variation on answer by [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) to allow for -9223372036854775808, along with a pos/neg sign at the front.

```
\b(?:[+-]?(?:[0-9]{1,18}|[1-8][0-9]{18}|9(?:[01][0-9]{17}|2(?:[01][0-9]{16}|2(?:[0-2][0-9]{15}|3(?:[0-2][0-9]{14}|3(?:[0-6][0-9]{13}|7(?:[01][0-9]{12}|20(?:[0-2][0-9]{10}|3(?:[0-5][0-9]{9}|6(?:[0-7][0-9]{8}|8(?:[0-4][0-9]{7}|5(?:[0-3][0-9]{6}|4(?:[0-6][0-9]{5}|7(?:[0-6][0-9]{4}|7(?:[0-4][0-9]{3}|5(?:[0-7][0-9]{2}|80[0-7]))))))))))))))))|-9223372036854775808)\b
```

Boundary conditions:

- 9223372036854775807
- +9223372036854775807
- 9223372036854775808
- +9223372036854775808
- -9223372036854775808
- -9223372036854775809